# unit vector conceptual

Tags: vectors

For the following, is it always going to be equal to 1?
$$\left|\frac{\vec{r}}{\vec{r}}\right|$$

Comment: Your second expression should be $(\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}})$ and not $\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}$. Consequently, your third expression should consist of all plus signs only.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant! Sorry for typo.

Comment: The expression $|\frac{\vec{r}}{\vec{r}}|$ doesn't make much sense since division of vectors isn't really a thing. However, it **is** true that $$\frac{\Vert \vec{r} \Vert}{\Vert \vec{r} \Vert}=1$$ since clearly the numerator and denominator are the same

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few minus sign errors in your intermediate steps. But the final answer of $1$ is correct, and that is always going to be the case. i.e it is always true that for $\mathbf{r} \neq 0$, $\left\lVert \dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{\lVert \mathbf{r} \rVert} \right\rVert = \dfrac{\lVert \mathbf{r} \rVert}{ \lVert \mathbf{r} \rVert } = 1$.

Basically, it's saying that the length of the vector obtained by dividing the original vector by its length is $1$.